# How to fixed messed up encoding in R?

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, codepages

I have a folder of files (~1000 files) and I wanted to replace a string in all of them with another string. The issue is that these files contain characters like "à", which get messed up when converting to ANSI. I thought I had taken every precaution to make sure R wouldn't mess everything up with its inexplicable preference to turn every string it gets it hands on into ANSI, however I failed. I hadn't tested it enough and now every file I have has every single special character messed up.
I know it can be undone, because through trial and error I found the following actions in Notepad++ undoes the damage R has done, under the encoding tab click:
convert to UTF-8
convert to ANSI
encode in UTF-8
However I'd prefer if I didn't have to manually correct the 1000 files. Is there a way in R to do the same thing? I included the code that messed up the files below. To replicate the problem:
1. create a file in notepad++ (or any other text editor) in UTF-8 encoding containing only the letter "à" (note the accent).
2. Save the file in an otherwise empty folder.
3. Set the sourcefolder-variable of the code below to this folder.
4. run the code below.

```
subInFiles <-function()
{
  utf8Write <- function(con, msg="") {
         con <- file(con, encoding = "UTF-8")
         tryCatch({
               cat(iconv(msg, to="UTF-8"), file=con, sep="\n")
           },
           finally = {
                 close(con)
             })
  }
  sourceFolder <- file.path("~", "myFolder")
  targetFolder <- sourceFolder
  names <- list.files(sourceFolder)
  regexMatch <- "someString"
  regexReplace <- "anotherString"
  fileContents <- sapply(names, function(name){ paste0(readLines( con = file.path(sourceFolder, name), encoding = "UTF-8" ), collapse = "\n") })
  print(fileContents[1])
  sapply(1:length(names), function(i) { utf8Write(con = file.path(targetFolder, names[i]), gsub(regexMatch, regexReplace, fileContents[i])) })
  return()
}
```

edit: thanks for the responses. Re alistaire: I agree that preventing is better than solving. However the mistake has been made at this point. The encoding of my files has been messed up, so no I have no choice but ask for fixes instead of better code.
Re JoseF: the issue becomes visible by the following lines of code:

```
 readLines( con = file.path(sourceFolder, name), encoding = "UTF-8" )
 readLines( con = file.path(sourceFolder, name), encoding = "ANSI" )
```

If we start with a file with as content "à\n", we get as output for these 2 lines:
[1] "à"
[1] "ï»¿Ã "
However after applying the above function the same lines applied to the same file give:
[1] "Ã "
[1] "ÃƒÂ "

Comment: Do you mean ASCII? R can handle encodings pretty gracefully, so rather than fix the issue after the fact, it's probably better to go fix the original code. Start by checking your locale.

Comment: I appreciate your instructions to reproduce that something _get messed up_ (but how?). However, [edit] your question to share the **desired behaviour** and a **specific problem or error**, please. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].